# adding image field to "Taxonomy term view"

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, media

I try to create a product catalog instead of using drupal commerce in drupal 7 with current updates.
I create product types related to categories which are taxonomy terms.
I create a menu as taxonomy terms.
If select a taxonomy terms from menu , it is listed all products under that terms.
Listing is controlled by taxonomy term view. There we can control only node title.
I want to find a way to add image related to that node also. Is there a module for that purpose? Or how could it be achieved?
Regards,

Comment: what do you mean @there we can control only node title.@ ? How can you control it??
Might you mean term name?

Comment: We add contents with taxonomy reference (added product put in related  product categories). When you select a category from menu , all products under that category is listed by node name.

Comment: Let me give you an example ;
This is category tree : Computers\Notebooks\HP\Pavilion
These are Taxonomy terms and menu items also.
I have computer content type ,
and add 5 Pavilion model , (PV1,PV2...PV5)

Comment: When I select Pavilion , drupal lists all 5 pavilion models with their name. You see anly node name there. What i want to add their thumbnail images next to them.
I hope I am  clear.

Comment: all i can see , there is view called taxonomy term(node).
When i try to edit, i could not find a way for image for content

Comment: when you click on term you see teasers of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on term you see teasers of nodes. few solutions for you:

1. You can change teaser of node in node display settings.
2. You can enable taxonomy/term/% view and customize it as you want
3. Also here is some [article](http://www.webomelette.com/how-customize-taxonomy-term-page-drupal-7-views)

Comment: Thank you milkovsky , problem is i can not see fields option in format setting.

Comment: please provide screenshot

Comment: http://i41.tinypic.com/2rgn8g2.jpg

Comment: On you screenshot you've choosen "Table". Table works authomaticaly with fields. Use "Fields" area below "Format" to add fields...

Comment: Do you know how to use `Views` module?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on below link ;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012999/how-to-display-all-taxonomy-term-fields-when-adding-node-in-drupal

I had already have entity reference module , but no entity reference view widget.
After i installed "entity reference view widget" , i could view image field in taxonomy term view.